# How to use dynamic variable in python mongodb script

Tags: python, mongodb

I want to update records in the collection books.
I want to create new field whose name and value are the values from variables.

```
for book in db.books.find():
    title = book['title']
    author, value = getAuthor(title)
    db.dataset.update({"_id": book['_id']}, {"$set": {author: value}})
```

When I did this I got the error: WriteError: The update path contains an empty field name. It is not allowed which is not true because both variables have values. I googled and resolved this issue by enclosing author into []. So the code looks like this:

```
for book in db.books.find():
    title = book['title']
    author, value = getAuthor(title)
    db.dataset.update({"_id": book['_id']}, {"$set": {[author]: value}})
```

But now I am getting this error which I am not able to resolve:
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Does anyone have encountered such problem? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `getAuthor()` is returning back nothing for it's first value, so `author` is getting set to nothing. From what I can see you did *not* resolve the error, you just changed it to a different error. By making it say `[author]` (though it's been a while since I've been in Python) I believe you're just trying to set the key to be an empty list, or a list with an empty string as the only value, depending on what `author` is.

If I were you, I would print out what `author` is, or do some debugging and figure out what you're getting back from `getAuthor()`. Since I can't see that code, nor the data in your database, I'm not sure how to help further without more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as stated in the Question both variables have value. getAuthor() is always returning a value. It always returns non empty string.

Comment: Yes, but in the question you haven't explained how you know that or if you're just assuming it. Often times strange errors for me are when one of my assumptions are wrong. Either way, I think you should solve the first problem because `[author]` is a list literal, trying to set the key to a list and not a string.

Comment: I debbuged it and printed all the values so I saw it is not empty. How can I solve then the first problem? Is there some otherway than enclosing it into []?